# Reliable Method to perform web searches using intents

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an app that will on a fragment page, provide a list of charities to call should they be distressed, initial testing had been fine, then I began noticing that clicking the websites onCLickListeners sometimes wouldn't work.

After a while, I realised that pressing the listener enough would eventually bring up the relevant site. Can anyone tell me how to make this more reliable?

As you can imagine, if you need to get some info then and there when distressed, having to click a link 3 times to bring up a website is poor.

Example of my code:

CharityPageFragment

```
    val char1Web = "gamcare.org.uk"
    binding.tvCharityOne.text = char1Name

    binding.tvCharityOneWebsite.setOnClickListener {
            webIntent(char1Web)
        }
```

...

```
private fun webIntent(website: String) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH)
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, website)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: You do not appear to have a listener. You are using `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`, which will bring up one of a variety of possible apps. How those apps behave is up to the developers of those apps, not you or I.

Comment: @CommonsWare Accidentally didn't include that when I copied the code over, but it was still in there

Comment: @CommonsWare However, you are saying that this is out of my control, that's a shame

Comment: The problem is that we do not know what "clicking the websites onCLickListeners sometimes wouldn't work" means. First, there is the question of what "clicking the websites onCLickListeners" means. For example, do you mean that tapping `tvCharityOneWebsite` does not always work? If so, is the problem in your app, or is the problem in the `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` activity that you are starting? You can distinguish between the two via logging, breakpoints, or other things to see if/when your listener is being called.